# How To Add +6 Months in current date

Tags: php, date

i want to add 6 months in current date. i have used the following date format.

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d');
```

i have proceed with this method shown below but an error is occured.

'A non well formed numeric value encountered'.
and print this value
 `[expiring_plan_date] => 1970-01-02`

```
$data['PlanPayment']['expiring_plan_date'] = date
                                           (
                                            "Y-m-d", 
                                            strtotime("+6 month", $current_time)
                                           );
```

please help..

Comment: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 month"));` just use this

Comment: thanks..yes it works perfectly..its my mistake to take wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma from `strtotime`

```
$data['PlanPayment']['expiring_plan_date'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 month $current_time));
```